What about the other 35 children who were born in the same manner in The Umbrella Academy. Do we hear what happened to them in the comic or TV Show?
I never read the comics and have recently watched the first 2 seasons.
Apparently in both the comics and the TV show they stated that 43 women who had not been pregnant, gave birth to super powered babies on the same day (October 1, 1989).
[EDIT: S3e1 Hargreeves' voice over at the beginning says 16 women. But I could have sworn an earlier episode from S1 or S2 said 43 women.] Hmm, I guess it was only 16 in the Sparrow Academy universe. Harlan's Pulse having killed 27 of the mothers before they could even start to give birth..
We know that Hargreeves was able to adopt 7 of them and The Handler kidnapped Lila after having her parents killed when she was 4. (TV Series)
But is there ever any mention of what happened to the rest of the 35 other special children in either the comic or the tv series?
If they know how many there were, someone had to have been keeping track of them/ or tracked them down.

I have finished the TV series, In the original time line, nothing is mentioned of the other mothers/children. But the TUA Apocalypse Comic series strongly implies that few of the babies other than the ones adopted by Hargraves survived long after birth.

According to TV tropes page, what happened to the other 36 children has not so far been revealed.
Umbrella Academy 2019

What Happened to the Mouse?: The identities or fates of the other 36 superpowered babies from spontaneous pregnancies are never addressed in the first season, although it is mentioned that not all of them survived past birth.
Leonard/Harold isn't one of them, but Lila is. Season 3 reveals six more of them, which were adopted (along with Ben) by Reginald in an alternate timeline to form the Sparrow Academy


Season 4 does not bring in any more super-powered individuals. Only the family and Lila appear to be of any consequence in shaping the finale around the Marigold and Durango. And Season 4 appears to be the conclusion of the Netflix series.

Didn't we see another one adopted in Season 4 in the Phoenix Academy universe? Arabic looking chap with fireballs? Or was he meant to be an earlier version of one of the Sparrows?

@SeanCondon whoa, spoiler alert :)

@Jontia I think if you're going to answer a question about a series with 4 seasons, you have to be prepared that someone might share information about the 4th season

Sorry I almost deleted that because it felt too abrupt on reread, but I think it might still appear in your notifications so that feels rude also. I meant to say I don't think Sean Condon's comment deserves a spoiler warning since it's under the answer to a question that's clearly about the entire series, so site visitors have ample time to not read the answers if they don't want to be spoiled for Umbrella Academy.

@KernelPanic no that's fine. I readily acknowledge the danger of going into questions where I've not seen the end of the show. Hence the smiley. That said the TV tropes page does contain numerous references to season 4 and still has an unchanged 'What happend to the mouse' section, which is why I felt comfortable post it as an answer. There may well be more in Season 4, which hasn't reached the wider net, but when posting a negative answer it's difficult to quote a primary source.
